# How do I embed the version from pyproject.toml so my package can use it?

Tags: python-import, python-packaging, python-poetry, python-importlib

The version in my project is stored in `pyproject.toml`:

```ini
[tool.poetry]
name = "package_name"
version = "1.2.3"
# ...
```

I now want to have a `__version__` in `package_name/__init__.py` as well and the general suggestion seems to be:

```py
import importlib_metadata

__version__ = importlib_metadata.version('package_name')
```

But that doesn't work for me. The moment I run my unittests I get this error:

```
importlib_metadata.PackageNotFoundError: No package metadata was found for package_name
```

How can I make this work during development?

Comment: Make sure that `package_name` is actually installed, because it needs to be installed otherwise no actual metadata is created for `importlib.metadata` to read. -- Also you do not need `__version__`; it is an outdated practice that was never standardized and I would remove it if I were you.

Comment: @sinoroc I'm developing the package, how am I supposed to install the package before I have built it?

Comment: Install as what is called "editable", which is Poetry's default behavior anyway. I guess run `poetry install` and you should be good to go. -- It is needed to re-run `poetry install` after every change of the "metadata" in `pyproject.toml` to re-generate the installed metadata with the new values.

Answer (score -2):

You can try add this to `__init__`:

```
from ._version import version as __version__
```

[source](https://scikit-hep.org/developer/packaging#versioning-mediumhigh-priority)